# IMPORTHTML return data that has column has partition as a date format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have sport data that I imported from [an api](https://www.betexplorer.com/hockey/japan/japan-cup/standings/?table=table&table_sub=&ts=begojFEk&dcheck=0)

```
#   Team                 MP W   WO  LO  L   G       Pts Form
1.  Red Eagles Hokkaido  26 20  2   0   4   110:55  64  
2.  Nikko Ice Bucks      24 15  0   3   6   106:65  48  
3.  Tohoku Free Blades   28 11  4   3   10  98:82   44  
4.  East Hokkaido Cranes 26 8   4   2   12  86:85   34  
5.  Yokohama Grits       28 1   1   3   23  44:157  8
```

There is a particular column named G in which, two data are combined and partitioned with column(:) (attached is the pic) [the pic of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0hmf.jpg). So when the column is imported into the sheet, it changes format to something else with additional column e.g 56:45:00.  Not sure if it's a date format, sometimes it rounds it up.  Please kindly provide a way around it. Thanks

Comment: The OP has remarked `check the 2nd row of the column, the initial data was 106:65, but the imported record has been round up to 107:05:00. That's what is challenging for me, so that's why I need a solution to importhtml function to bring exact data [...] In addition, pls note that the table is dynamic, for the table that has not entered 100, i.e 93:90 won't be converted to hh:mm:ss format, i believe it will be mm:ss. So, I need something that will take this into consideration and there won't be error no matter the type of data. `

Comment: `IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML assigns the data type before adding the values to the spreadsheet.` @Rubén in [a WebApps question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/100468/196152). In short, you can't change the operation of `IMPORTXTML`. Workarounds?  **Formula**: In that question, a value was interpreted as a date and there _was_ a workaround. But in this case 106.65 => 107:05 (65 minutes => 1 hour:05minutes), there's no way to know whether or not the true value _was_ 107:05 (which is a valid result). **Script**: using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`, a script will retrieve the true value (106.65).

Comment: Is there UrlFetchApp.fetch() in google sheet.  Can you help me out with the solution

Comment: I read about UrlFetchApp.fetch() and learnt it work on google app script.  I don't know how to use i,  but I understand it might work like a macro.  I don't really like macro because I am not sure if I can have different script for each sheet I open in the workbook. For the web question you cited,  I have check through it for days now and couldn't replicate Ruben and Aurielle answer.  But I think they were able to solve it. But the function didn't work for me,  maybe because I didn't understand what to add or removed.

Comment: “But the function didn't work for me” I tried the function too but the reason that it doesn’t work is that it was referencing a date. In your case, it is delivering a “duration”, which is why 106:65 becomes 107:05: the minutes element MUST be less than 60 which is why 65 is converted into one hour and 05 minutes.  And this is why **a formula workaround using IMPORTHTML won’t work in this case**. You will never know whether 107:05 was the real value or a converted value.